# is it possible to have 22 audio files playing at once (for a live radio effect)

Tags: audio, loading, filesize

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve a live radio effect with 22 channels. There are 22 audio files, each under a minute long. I imagine all playing at once, but on mute. Hovering over a channel's button will unmute its audio. Is this plausible?

EDIT for clarification: This is for a website viewed on your desktop browser. The audio files would be inside HTML audio tags. The hover-unmute mechanic would use JQuery, I imagine.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide the bare minimum information to help you e.g. the context of where this audio will actually be playing (a phone app, website, Windows application??) and what technology, specifically the programming language, that you intend to use.

Comment: Rather than playing everything on mute, I would start and stop the audio and the appropriate position when the rollover happens. That should give the desired effect?

Comment: interesting, could you explain how you would go about that? i'm imagining a timer variable that counts when the page loads and then I use that value in a jquery function?

Comment: Yes, you would use that timer to specify the start position of the audio file when it plays. Good luck.

Comment: I guess there is no problem about playing 22 audio files simultaneously. What is your question exactly?